# How to create Swift empty two dimensional array for add value later

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know how to declare variable empty 2D Array for set value in 2D Array with fix row

I try to declare like this

```
var Memberlist = [[String]]()
```

and set value like this

```
Memberlist[0][1] = "abc"
```

it can't set value because it out of range

what should I do

and this is full code

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "memberNameCell", for: indexPath)

                 if let member = groupController.groups[indexPath.section].members[indexPath.row] as? Member
                 {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = member.name
                    //Memberlist[indexPath.section] = [indexPath.row:member.name]
                    Memberlist[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = member.name

                 }


        return cell

    }
```

Comment: let subArray = ["first", "second"]
Memberlist.append(subArray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Memberlist.append(newarray)` or `Memberlist[j].insert("VALUE", at: i)` to add/insert a new array/value:

```
    var Memberlist = [[String]]()

    var newarray = ["first", "second"]
    newarray.append("third")
    Memberlist.append(newarray)
```

Or

```
    let arr0 = ["first0", "first1", "first2"]
    let arr1 = ["second0", "second1", "second2", "second3"]
    let arr2 = ["third0", "third1", "third2"]

    var Memberlist = [arr0, arr1, arr2]
    if Memberlist[j].count > i {
       Memberlist[j].insert("VALUE", at: i)
    } else {
        Memberlist[j][i] = "VALUE"
    }
```

Comment: I can't use .append because I must to set value fix row.

Comment: Ok. We can create an matrix on destination size.

Comment: In each row of The array has different variables. what should I do ToT

Comment: Ok. Where come from your values? Can you show me?